# Mongodb regex not matching exact when . (dot) in search

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to check if email already registered in my MongoDB database or not.
I have one user registered with `test123@test.com`
But If I check for `test.23@test.com` it still matches record of `test123@test.com`  
I tried following queries

```
db.getCollection('users').find(
     {"email":{ $regex: new RegExp(test.23@test.com, "i") } 
})

db.getCollection('users').find(
         {"email":{ $regex: new RegExp(/test.23@test.com/, "i") } 
})

db.getCollection('users').find(
         {"email":{ $regex: new RegExp(/^(test.23@test.com)$/, "i") } 
})

db.getCollection('users').find(
         {"email":{ $regex: new RegExp(/^(test.23@test\.com)$/, "i") } 
})
```

How can I search exact match with case insensitive?

Comment: That dot matches any character except a newline, so 1 would also match. If you want ot match it literally you have to escape it like `\.`.

Comment: `new RegExp(/test123@test.com\./, "i")` i tried this but it's not even matching actual

Comment: You added a dot after the email. I think it should be `new RegExp(/test123@test\.com/, "i")` but if you want to find it literally, why use a regex?

Comment: `new RegExp(/test.23@test\.com/, "i")` this is still matching `test123@test.com`

Comment: That should be `new RegExp(/test\.23@test\.com/, "i")` Note the first escaped dot as well.

Comment: `new RegExp(/test\.123@test\.com/, "i")` this is not matching `test123@test.com`
Also, email is coming dynamically, so I can't escape statically as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do regex. Mongodb support [collations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) since v3.4

```
db.getCollection('users').find(
     {"email":"test.23@test.com"} 
).collation(
     {locale:"en", strength: 1}
)
```

will match "test.23@test.com", "TEST.23@TEST.COM" and anything in between.

As a side note passing user's input straight to the regex query you risk to lose your server one day. Read for inspiration https://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html If you decide to proceed with regex approach you can escape dots at the time when you escape parenthesis, brackets, escape character and other special symbols from regex syntax.